# Can I use Flink's filesystem connector as lookup tables?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Flink 1.13.2 (Flink SQL) on Yarn.

A bit confused - I found two (as I understand) different specifications of Filesystem connector (Ververica.com vs ci.apache.org):

1. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/overview/#supported-connectors — Filesystem is "Bounded and Unbounded Scan, **Lookup**"
2. https://docs.ververica.com/user_guide/sql_development/connectors.html#packaged-connectors — Only JDBC marked as usable for Lookup.

Can I use Filesystem connector (csv) for creating lookup (dimension) tables to enrich Kafka events table? If yes - how it's possible using Flink SQL?

(I've tried simple left joins with `FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF a.event_datetime` - it's works in test environment with small amount of Kafka events, but in production I get `GC overhead limit exceeded` error. I guess that's because of not broadcasting small csv tables to worker nodes. In Spark I used to solve these type problems using related hints.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookup(dimension) table needs to implement the LookupTableSource interface, currently only hbase, jdbc, and hive are implemented in the Flink 1.3 version

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The filesystem connector shouldn't be used as a lookup because lookup access needs indexed access. We should update the documentation for this.

Comment: Dear Martijn, can you please share list of connectors available to use as lookup tables? Is there hive connector on this list?

Comment: For Flink 1.13, it's currently JDBC, HBase and Hive